# Find $V(x,y)$ such that $\nabla V(x,y)\cdot (x^2-y,x)\leq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find $V(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $V(0,0)=0$, $V(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $$\nabla V(x,y)\cdot (x^2-y,x)\leq 0,\text{ for all }(x,y).$$

I have to been proving with several functions, like the function which have as gradient $(y,-xy)$, since $$(y,-xy)\cdot (x^2-y,x)=yx^2-y^2-x^2y=-y^2\leq 0$$, but that $V$ with $V_x=y$ and $V_y=-xy$ doesn't exists, because for a side $$V(x,y)=yx+f(y)$$ and for other side $$V(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2}xy^2+g(x).$$
And thus I've to been trying but I don´t have success. Any help it'll be appreciate.